# MySQL replication, ignore stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, replication, mariadb

For tables we have:
**--replicate-ignore-table=db_name.tbl_name**
Is there something similar for stored procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such feature.

As a workaround you could revoke the `CREATE ROUTINE` privilege for replication user and set `slave_skip_errors` to `ON` (which I wouldn't recommend).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DATABASE DontReplicateMe;  -- where you will put the SP

--replicate-ignore-db = DontReplicateMe  -- keep it replicating

USE DontReplicateMe;   -- controls the repl stuff
CREATE PROCEDURE ...   -- finally create it.
```

Also, this would probably work:

```
USE DontReplicateMe;   -- controls the repl stuff
CREATE PROCEDURE YourDatabase.SP_Name ...   -- finally create it.
```

Note that the `USE` controls what gets replicated, while `YourDatabase.SP_Name` says where it lives.